# Split parameter and use it as multiple arguments

Tags: ansible, rsync

I'm trying to create a reusable role that does a synchronize where I pass in the `src`, `dest` and an `exclude` parameters.

I'd like to split that exclude parameter into multiple `--exclude=` parameters if it's defined.

So, effectively what would be running is:

With exclude undefined:

```yaml
- name: Copy extracted files to remote
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ src }}"
    dest: "{{ dest }}"
    rsync_opts:
      - "--no-motd"
```

With `exclude=logs,conf`:

```yaml
- name: Copy extracted files to remote
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ src }}"
    dest: "{{ dest }}"
    rsync_opts:
      - "--no-motd"
      - "--exclude=logs"
      - "--exclude=conf"
```

I figure I need to split the variable, but I'm not sure how to add the `--exclude=` to each one, whilst not adding any if there's nothing passed.

Comment: How exactly do you envision the exclude parameter to be passed to that role? As a list, I guess?

Comment: Preferably as a list, but if that's not possible I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are passing the `exclude` parameter to your role via:

```yaml
roles:
  - role: demo_role
    src: /path/to/src
    dest: /path/to/dest
    exclude:
      - logs
      - conf
```

Then, in your `synchronize` task, you could use a [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) filter, in order to construct the exclusions path along with the `--exclude` flag:

```yaml
rsync_opts: >-
  {{
    ['--no-motd']
    + ['--exclude=']
      | product(exclude | default([]))
      | map('join')
  }}
```

From there:

- when `exclude` is a list:

  ```yaml
  exclude:
     - logs
     - conf
  ```

  `rsync_opts` will be:

  ```yaml
  - --no-motd
  - --exclude=logs
  - --exclude=conf
  ```
- when `exclude` is an empty list:

  ```yaml
  exclude: []
  ```

  `rsync_opts` will be:

  ```yaml
  - --no-motd
  ```
- when `exclude` is undefined:

  ```yaml
  - role: demo_role
    src: /path/to/src
    dest: /path/to/dest
  ```

  `rsync_opts` will be:

  ```yaml
  - --no-motd
  ```

  thanks to the usage of the [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) filter

Comment: On ansible 2.9.27

Comment: Still failing I'm afraid :(

MSG:

Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{
  ['--no-motd']
  + ['--exclude=']
    | product(exclude | default([]))
    | map('join')
}}): can only concatenate list (not "generator") to list

Comment: You are on an EOL version of Ansible, all I could recommend is to upgrade to a newer version (where you won't have this issue, either).

Comment: But what you could try is to add a `| list` after the `map` filter.

Comment: That did work :D

    rsync_opts: >-
      {{
        ['--no-motd']
        + ['--exclude=']
          | product(exclude | default([]))
          | map('join') | list
      }}

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you add that onto the above I'll mark it as the solution thanks

Comment: @MikeLothian as I said in the comment above, this is only needed on Ansible version < 2.10, and since the 2.9.x branch is EOL since last year, adding that in the answer will make it an outdated way of achieving it. Since the goal of a Q&A like StackOverflow is to have accurate and up-to-date answer, adding it in the answer is not the way to go, the way to go is **upgrade your version of Ansible to a supported one**, then the code above would work.